# How to catch the event on input type 'text' on value change without the window refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

**As whenever I select any value from dropdown list, the page is refreshed(window element is clicked which I dont want).**

1st TS file dynamically inserting input field value when the element is selected from dropdown

```
private inputboxTrayselectionString: string = "*[data-type='tag']";       
base.$inputbox = base.$rootElement.find(base.inputboxTrayselectionString).eq(0);
base.$inputbox.val(dataArr.toString()).change();

$(window).click(function(e) {
   console.log('window clicked'); 
   base.$optionTray.hide();
});
```

=> 2nd TS file catching the event

```
this.filterElByTagnew = $(this.rootElementSelectionString + ' input[data-type="tag"]');   
this.filterElByTagnew.on('change', function (e) { self.cummulativeOnChangeHandler();});
```

HTML to show the dropdown

```
<div class="eG2Col blog-inline-form">
   <label>Filter:</label>
   <div class="js-multiselectDropdown">
      <div style="background-color: white">
         <div class="action-btn " data-action="colex">    <span>Choose Tag</span></div>
         <input type="text" data-type="tag" >
         <div class="eG2Col list-show" data-action="option-tray">
            <ul></ul>
         </div>
         <div data-action="checkbox-tray" class="hidden">
            <input type="checkbox" value="5G" />5G</br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Connectivity"  />Connectivity</br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Digital transformation" />Digital transformation</br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Radio system"  />Radio system</br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Mobile"  />Mobile</br>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that you click the dropdown to interact with it. Through a mechanism known as *event bubbling*, this click counts as a click on the window, because the window is an ancestor of the dropdown.

Handle the `click` event on the dropdown and call [`stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to prevent event handlers on ancestors from running.